# NumberFormatException thrown on a correct String?

Tags: java, parsing, integer, numberformatexception

I'm trying to parse a file into a Map. The text I'm trying to parse (displayed by sys out in log) is

`10    przysuń hotel   o   90  metrów`. With each word separated by `\t`

The file is UTF-8 encoded.

Here's my method:

```
 private void readFile() {
    try {
        if (transcriptFile == null)
            transcriptFile = new File(transcriptPath);

        lines = Files.readAllLines(transcriptFile.toPath());
        for (String s : lines) {
            if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(s.split("\t"));
                System.out.println(parts);

                int id = Integer.parseInt(parts.get(0).trim());
                parts.remove(0);
                String text = String.join(" ",parts);
                map.put(id,text);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this exception:

```
[﻿10, przysuń, hotel, o, 90, metrów ]
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "﻿10"
at 
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at Controller.readFile(Controller.java:143)
at Controller.access$000(Controller.java:29)
at Controller$SpeechTask.call(Controller.java:202)
at Controller$SpeechTask.call(Controller.java:154)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I see no reason why this would not be parsable.

Comment: Perhaps there are some invisible special characters in the string? What if you strip all non-digits first, try `int id = Integer.parseInt(parts.get(0).replaceAll("\\D+", ""));`

Comment: Potentially a character encoding issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Your input file may contain a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), a non-visible character which could be located immediately before the characters `10`. Try the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java#1835529) or Apache's [BOMInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html)

Non-programmatically, you could use Notepad++'s *Encode in UTF-8 without BOM*
feature and save the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Can u replace the following line

```
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(s.split("\t"));
```

With this and check once

```
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(s.replaceAll("\\s+", ",").split(","));
```

And tell is the same exception coming again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is because of a character encoding issue, notepad saved some additional characters in front of the file when defining the encoding as UTF-8.

When i try this, `parts.get(0).trim()` returned `?10` not `10` thus there was a `NumberFormatException`. Suppose if you have defined the `10` as a second word then `parts.get(1).trim()` would return `10` and there wouldn't be any `NumberFormatException`

Following question explain this issue [Reading strange unicode character in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889064/reading-strange-unicode-character-in-java)

Further `Arrays.asList` returns a list that can't be modified, so there could be a `UnsupportedOperationException` in `parts.remove(0)` even though `Integer.parseInt` success.

Comment: regarding your last point, I changed it to `parts = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\t"));` so removing element should not be an issue.